# Decompress .exi file using javascript and viceversa

Tags: javascript, xml, grammar, exi

How can we decompress an .exi file in my laptop using javascript?
   Could you please tell me how to do it? (suggestions on any links with examples doing the same is also welcome.)

Question in detail:
        I have a .exi file with me(I downloaded a sample .exi file from internet). I need to decompress/decode the file to XML file format or as XML string using javascript.  I tried to implement the same with https://github.com/EXIficient/exificient-for-javascript. Inside this link, there is a demo app, http://exificient.github.io/javascript/demo/processXML.html
in which I gave a .exi file to parse it and tried to decode it. When I clicked on decode button, it gave back a message as [image]  It asks for json grammar file with extension '.xsd.grs', which seems to be the schema file, I guess. How can we create a grammar file, if so? I don't know how to do the same. I need to learn how to convert an xml file to .exi file too using javascript. I hope this makes the doubt much clear. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to describe your requirement a little more detailed, especially exi  extension is very uncommon and might be interpreted in various ways...

Comment: "it asks for json grammar file" is very hard to interpret. What is "it"? Please specify *exactly* what you tried and *exactly* what the result was, copy-and-pasting error messages literally into the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exificient works well when we try to provide a correct .exi file along with its corresponding grammar file( the file with extension *.xsd.grs with which the .exi file was made). If proper .exi and .xsd.grs files are given, the file is parsed and displayed in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

As the JavaScript implementation is still in an early stage, exificient.js (as mentioned before) requires pre-processed grammar files.

EXI grammar files are based on an XML schema. To generate the according grammars files for the JS implementation one needs to generate it once with the Java implementation.

https://github.com/EXIficient/exificient-grammars/

The according class is https://github.com/EXIficient/exificient-grammars/blob/master/src/main/java/com/siemens/ct/exi/grammars/persistency/Grammars2JSON.java

Hope this helps,

-- Daniel

P.S. For processing EXI4JSON streams the JavaScript implementation does not need that additional step given that the grammars are built-in. One can do the same for a given XML schema use-case.